# Stopping/Starting IIS using VB console application (bypass Admin rights)

Tags: vb.net, iis, console-application

I'm trying to stop the `IIS` using a **vb script** but I have to bypass the admin rights prompt. Here's what I found from google but it doesn't seem to be working. What I'm trying to do is run the `exe` then automatically stops the IIS (No prompt that requires me to select Yes or No). Is there something wrong with the code? Or am I missing a Namespace import?

```
Try
   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("iisreset /stop")
Catch ex As Exception
   Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace.ToString())
End Try
```

Comment: "it doesn't seem to be working" is not a clear problem description. Note that `Process.Start` is non-blocking - it will return before the specified program completes.

Comment: If there was a way to bypass the admin prompt..... then people would already be writing viruses to do it.